# Lightning calendars appears, but all tasks and appointment are gone after profile import

Tags: lightning

I moved from Ubuntu 20 to 22. Thunderbird 115.8 profile zipped on Ubuntu 20. After installation (Ubuntu 22) I used Thunderbird's import tool: everything went well, but all of my calendars are blank. All appears, but no tasks, no appointments, nothing. Lightning not shows up as an extension.

I installed an Ubuntu 20 on Virtualbox, thinking, I may can get back my calendar data, but the same happened: Thunderbird imports mails, addressbooks, etc, but no calendar data.

Official Tunderbird help says I have to ask you guys:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/calendar-updates-issues-thunderbird

Meanwhile, Thunderbird updated to 115.9

I'm out of ideas but urgently need my calendar data. Is anybody has any idea?
Or, we can bypass Thunderbird if you know how to get back calendar data from saved Thunderbird profile (default.zip).
Many thanks lads

Answer (score 1):

If anyone struggling with this, copy the contents of saved `calendar-data` folder into the live profile's `calendar-data` folder. All appointments will show up. (but shutdown Thunderbird first)